# Laravel 5.8 Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <optional> $message ]] in class Exception

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.8

I have created `CustomInvalidInputException` with `php artisan make:exception CustomInvalidInputException`.

In my `CustomerRepository.php` file I am raising the newly created `CustomInvalidInputException`.

But I am getting an exception as follows. Any help is appreciated.

```
[2019-09-22 04:21:25] local.ERROR: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <optional> $message ]] in class Exception {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <optional> $message ]] in class Exception at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php:975)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(913): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->unresolvablePrimitive(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(854): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolvePrimitive(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(816): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(667): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('Exception')
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(615): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('Exception', Array)
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(767): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('Exception', Array)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('Exception')
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(121): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::addDependencyForCallParameter(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(ReflectionParameter), Array, Array)
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(32): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::getMethodDependencies(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array)
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(576): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(107): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(38): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(App\\Exceptions\\CustomInvalidInputException))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(81): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(App\\Exceptions\\CustomInvalidInputException))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(App\\Exceptions\\CustomInvalidInputException))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php(58): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 60, '1')
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\JSONMiddleware.php(11): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): App\\Http\\Middleware\\JSONMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(36): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#52 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\finance\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 {main}
"}
```

**CustomerRepository.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories\Customer;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Exceptions\CustomInvalidInputException;

class CustomerRepository
{
    public function validateInput($params = array(), $id = null)
    {
        throw new CustomInvalidInputException("Customer already exists with given email");
    }
}
```

**CustomInvalidInputException.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class CustomInvalidInputException extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'customer' => $exception->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ExceptionHandler.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use App\Exceptions\CustomInvalidInputException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof CustomInvalidInputException) {
            return $exception->render($request);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem attempting something like this:

```
return app(ArrayIterator::class, ['array' => $this->content]);
```

Same error, `BindingResolutionException` on an **optional** parameter. So I tinkered with Reflection directly just to experiment:

```
$class = new \ReflectionClass(ArrayIterator::class);
$method = $class->getMethod('__construct');
$parameters = $method->getParameters();
/** @var \ReflectionParameter $parameter */
$parameter = $parameters[1];
dd($parameter->getDefaultValue());
```

The error this resulted in was something to which Google was able to yield more clues:

`ReflectionException: Cannot determine default value for internal functions`

It looks like a [Reflection bug](https://github.com/theorchard/monolog-cascade/issues/37). The recommended solution in that thread is, as `Illuminate\Container\Container::resolvePrimitive()` does, check `$parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()` first. Evidently it returns `false` on parameters where the default value is invisible to Reflection, which does not necessarily mean they don't exist.

Means you and I will have to either `new` up internal classes, or explicitly re-declare the default values. So... I'd be happy if someone else could come in and prove me wrong, because neither solution is optimal.